# Filter items in VB.net datagrid in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, datagrid

WPF/VB.net newbie here.

I'm trying to filter rows in a datagrid and having a fun time.

I've managed to create a list of objects and use the itemsource property to get the datagrid to populate.

Now I have a checkbox that for arguments-sake I want to click and filter down only those rows that match this criterion.

With the code below I'm getting the general "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error but a bit lost.  I'm sure a VB pro will see it.

I'd prefer to do more in code, rather than XAML if possible.

This is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="displayGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="62,94,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="142" Width="360" SelectionChanged="DataGrid_SelectionChanged"/>
        <Button Content="Load" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="62,51,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="showOnlyChildren" Content="Show Only Children" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="172,51,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="147"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And this is my code:

```
Class MainWindow 

    Class person

        Property name
        Property age

    End Class

    Dim listOfPersons As New List(Of person)
    Private filteredList As CollectionViewSource

    Private Sub DataGrid_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

        Dim aPerson As New person With {
            .name = "Fred Smith",
            .age = 12}

        listOfPersons.Add(aPerson)

        Dim bPerson As New person With {
         .name = "Tom Jones",
         .age = 50}

        listOfPersons.Add(bPerson)

        displayGrid.ItemsSource = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listOfPersons)

    End Sub


    Private Sub ShowOnlyChildrenFilter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FilterEventArgs)
        Dim person As person = TryCast(e.Item, person)
        If person IsNot Nothing Then
            ' Filter out persons with age less than 18
            If person.age < 19 Then
                e.Accepted = True
            Else
                e.Accepted = False
            End If
        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub AddFiltering(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As RoutedEventArgs) Handles showOnlyChildren.Checked
        AddHandler filteredList.Filter, AddressOf ShowOnlyChildrenFilter
    End Sub

    Private Sub RemoveFiltering(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As RoutedEventArgs)
        RemoveHandler filteredList.Filter, AddressOf ShowOnlyChildrenFilter
    End Sub




End Class
```

EDIT:  OK slowly but surely getting there.  I'm incorporated some changes that I found [here](http://excelnoob.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-to-filter-listview-items-using.html) and thanks to help I got here....  This is what the code looks like now:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Class MainWindow

    Class person

        Property name
        Property age

    End Class

    Dim listOfPersons As New List(Of person)
    Private filteredList As CollectionViewSource
    Dim view As ICollectionView

    Private Sub DataGrid_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

        Dim aPerson As New person With {
            .name = "Fred Smith",
            .age = 12}

        listOfPersons.Add(aPerson)

        Dim bPerson As New person With {
         .name = "Tom Jones",
         .age = 50}

        listOfPersons.Add(bPerson)

        view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listOfPersons)
        displayGrid.ItemsSource = view

    End Sub


    Function ShowOnlyChildrenFilter(ByVal param As Object) As Boolean
        Dim person As person = TryCast(param, person)
        Dim retValue As Boolean

        If person IsNot Nothing Then
            ' Filter out persons with age less than 18
            If person.age < 19 Then
                retValue = True
            Else
                retValue = False
            End If
        End If

        Return retValue

    End Function

    Private Sub showOnlyChildren_Checked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles showOnlyChildren.Checked

        If showOnlyChildren.IsChecked = True Then
            view.Filter = New Predicate(Of Object)(AddressOf ShowOnlyChildrenFilter)
        Else
            'what goes here?
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

The only thing I'm missing is how to refresh the datagrid, when the checkbox is unchecked.  Thanks to all.   I'm still amazed at how complex and mindbending this is for what I would have thought would be quite simple.

Comment: What line gives you the error?

Comment: @Steve  AddHandler filteredList.Filter, AddressOf ShowOnlyChildrenFilter, when I click the checkbox.    I added New keyword in front of CollectionViewSource and it doesn't error now.  Just doesn't do what I want.

Comment: I do not see the line you are refering to in the code you posted??

Comment: @steve it is in the Sub AddFiltering

Comment: To be honest I cannot believe you have to pass some lambda function to get a datagrid to filter.  Is it deliberately complicated?

Comment: (Sorry, scrollbar). See answer I posted.

Comment: I don’t use dotNet controls mainly because of their grid. Third party may cost a little money but man, what a difference. Especially in ASP.

Comment: Regarding the use of a lambda: The CollectionViewSource API has no way of knowing what semantics might be used to filter the underlying collection (the CVS doesn't have a type argument for you to specify, after all). Passing in the implementation keeps your options for filtering as flexible as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK It is done.  Made a couple more newbie errors on the above code.  So here is the working version.  Tick a checkbox and it filters on a condition.

VB code:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Class MainWindow

    Class person

        Property name
        Property age

    End Class

    Dim listOfPersons As New List(Of person)
    Dim view As ICollectionView

    Private Sub DataGrid_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs)
        MsgBox("changed")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

        Dim aPerson As New person With {
            .name = "Fred Smith",
            .age = 12}

        listOfPersons.Add(aPerson)

        Dim bPerson As New person With {
         .name = "Tom Jones",
         .age = 50}

        listOfPersons.Add(bPerson)

        view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listOfPersons)
        displayGrid.ItemsSource = view

    End Sub


    Function ShowOnlyChildrenFilter(ByVal param As Object) As Boolean
        Dim person As person = TryCast(param, person)
        Dim retValue As Boolean

        If person IsNot Nothing Then
            ' Filter out persons with age less than 18
            If person.age < 19 Then
                retValue = True
            Else
                retValue = False
            End If
        End If

        Return retValue

    End Function

    Private Sub showOnlyChildren_Checked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles showOnlyChildren.Checked

        If showOnlyChildren.IsChecked = True Then
            view.Filter = New Predicate(Of Object)(AddressOf ShowOnlyChildrenFilter)
        End If


    End Sub

    Private Sub showOnlyChildren_UnChecked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles showOnlyChildren.Unchecked

        If showOnlyChildren.IsChecked = False Then
            view.Filter = Nothing
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

With XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="displayGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="62,94,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="142" Width="360" SelectionChanged="DataGrid_SelectionChanged"/>
        <Button Content="Load" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="62,51,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="showOnlyChildren" Content="Show Only Children" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="172,51,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="147"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be a comment and not an answer but I am unable to comment as not enough rep!

Have you tried using

[ICollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752348.aspx)

I have a C# example I can provide if you are able to convert it!

EDIT:

I thought I would just chuck in the example as it may help a little

```
private void cbBlahYear_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        lvwMainBlahFilter();
    }

    private void lvwMainBlahFilter()
    {
        ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lvwMainBlah.ItemsSource);

        view.Filter = null;
        view.Filter = new Predicate<object>(FilterBlahByYearID);
        view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Forename", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
    }

    private Boolean FilterBlahByYearID(object obj)
    {
        BlahModel item = obj as BlahModel;
        if (item == null) return false;

        Int32 myID = 0;
        if (cbBlahYear.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            YearModel year = cbBlahYear.SelectedItem as YearModel;
            myID = year.id;
        }

        if (myID == 0) return false;

        if (item.YearID == myID) return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Looks interesting.  Have you got the rest of it, like the class definition and dataloader, and the XAML?  There is so little around for VB.net I might have to migrate... all those curl braces are scary tho :)

Comment: well the cb is a combobox. the lvw is a listview and the FilterbyBlah is just a function. Change the syntax and you should be there.

Comment: Sorry I'm a completed newbie here. Here is my class:  
`class BlahModel
    {
        public object Forename { get; set; }
        public object YearID { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: And my code has some red lines underneath.  [screenshot](http://www.kbytes.co.uk/userfiles/images/SO%2DDB%2DQuestion(1).jpg)

Comment: The red is because you do not have a Year model. cbBlahYear is a combobox populated with a list of year models. This part of the code just takes the selected model from the combobox so that you may reference it's id field

Answer (score 0):

The variable `filteredList` that you are tring to:

```
AddHandler filteredList.Filter, AddressOf ShowOnlyChildrenFilter
```

Is still nothing at this line.  Try declaring it as NEW first:

```
Private filteredList As New CollectionV
```

Comment: I put a breakpoint on the 
    Dim person As person = TryCast(e.Item, person)
line and it never hits it.  Is that because of the function pass?

Comment: On the check of the button, you add a handler to the filteredList.Filter event, you aren't running the filter event. And, this will never fire because you never fill in the CollectionViewSource with data. I think you might need to set the `filteredList = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listOfPersons)` and then set `displayGrid.ItemsSource = filteredList`.